# Verify In-App Purchase from Google Play on Backend Node.js

Tags: node.js, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

I am working on an mobile app which have some kind of in-app-purchases..

Now on backend/Server-side i want to validate the purchase information from google . There are few module in node for validation but they just validate that data is correct but not contact google for the same.
can anyone give any suggations for the same..
In-app-purchase data is like i.e.

```
{
   "orderId":"12999763169054705758.1364365967744519",
   "packageName":"my package name",
   "productId":"77",
   "purchaseTime":1366217534000,
   "purchaseState":0,
   "purchaseToken":"utfwimslnrrwvglktizikdcd.AOJ1OwZ4l5oXz_3d2SAWAAUgFE3QErKoyIX8WuSEnBW26ntsyDmlLgoUd5lshqIY2p2LnlV4tpH4NITB4mJMX98sCtZizH7wGf6Izw3tfW_GflJDKFyb-g"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [iab_verifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iab_verifier) module for same

In this Google Play public key is required to authenticate the app billing

```
var IABVerifier = require('iab_verifier'),

var googleplay_public_key = "-- YOUR PUBLIC KEY --";
var googleplayVerifier = new IABVerifier(googleplay_public_key);

var receiptData = receiptDataFromClient;
var receiptSignature = signatureDataFromClient;

var isValid = googleplayVerifier.verifyReceipt(receiptData,receiptSignature);

if (result) {
    // Receipt is valid. Grab a beer celebrate!
} else {
    // Receipt is NOT valid... 
}
```

thanks

Comment: it just does key validation and data velidation.. No Verification from google end.....    IABVerifier.prototype.verifyReceipt = function(signedData, signature) {
        var verifier;
        verifier = crypto.createVerify(algorithm);
        verifier.update(signedData);
        return verifier.verify(this.publicKeyString, signature, 'base64');
    };

    return IABVerifier;

  }

Comment: What does signatureDataFromClient represent